# Spring secutiry custom authentication manager vs custom provider vs custom UserDetailsService

Tags: authentication, spring-security, customization

I've been knocking my head up against this problem for a few days now and after seeing dozens of examples all over the web I'm no closer to a solution.

I need to to various types of login, eventually. For right now I'd settle for one. I would like to login using fields other than username and password. Let's say I want to use name, last name and birthdate.

I thought the easiest way to go was to just implement my own UserDetailsService and plug it into my provider. But UserDetailsService only has one method, loadByUsername, which doesn't seem to be the most intuitive way to load my user.

So then I thought it would be better to implement my own AuthenticationProvider ... or simply extend DaoAuthenticationProvider, and override the authenticate() method. But that method takes an Authentication as a parameter ... can I used a POJO, with only name, last name and birthdate fields, as an Authentication object?

Ditto for Authentication Manager. In fact, in the api for AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider (where the authenticate() method lives) it says that it "Performs authentication with the same contract as AuthenticationManager.authenticate(Authentication)"

But people seem to implement Providers more than Managers. oddly enough, most examples of "custom" Providers and UserDetailsServices ... all implement authentication with username and password, which is was Spring Security does by default anyway!

Can anyone shed some light on this subject? As I said, there are tons of examples but they are all very similar and none that I can find use an Authentication Object that isn't username/password.

Bonus points if someone could also tell me the best way to go about having more than one Provider/Manager -- for example, one like the one described above, and another that authenticates using name and social security number, for example --  and to use one or the other (not both, and not the second one if the first one fails!) depending on a parameter pass from the url, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you had already solved this challenge. But, it seems that I have a similar case with you. My login page requires additional field 'organisation' aside from 'username' and 'password'. Here is what I did:

1. I've used custom AuthenticationManager and custom UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter.
2. The custom filter is for retrieving the additional field from HttpServletRequest. I added the field to the session and retrieved it inside custom AuthenticationManager.
3. Performed authentication with the three fields using another bean/service.